# flex property not working for nested div tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I was trying to achieve 0 and C button as twice the size of normal button and = button as twice in height (taller) as height of normal button.

What I've tried -

Div1 - Main Divison display flex and direction column.
Div2 - The input bar inside Div1.
Div3 - The whole divison of buttons.

Div3 - Contains Two Div as flex layout in row manner (Div4, Div5).
Div4 - Contains rows of divs which contain button except the buttons present inside last column.
Inside Div4 I was able to do flex:2 for the button I need twice as width.

Div5 - Last column of buttons But when I set flex:2 for "=" button It's height doesn't change.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/darshansharma/pen/poLOvwr)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> calculator </title>
    <script src="./calculator.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div id="textbox">
            <span type="text" id="tagone"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="buttondivision">
            <div class="calc-col1">
                <div class="calc-row">
                    <button id="clearbutton" onclick="clearfun()"> C</button>
                    <button id="percentbutton" onclick="percentfun()">%</button>

                </div>
                <div class="calc-row">
                    <button onclick="setvalue('7')"> 7 </button>
                    <button onclick="setvalue('8')"> 8 </button>
                    <button onclick="setvalue('9')"> 9</button>

                </div>
                <div class="calc-row">
                    <button onclick="setvalue('4')"> 4</button>
                    <button onclick=" setvalue('5')"> 5 </button>
                    <button onclick="setvalue('6')"> 6</button>

                </div>
                <div class="calc-row">
                    <button onclick="setvalue('1')"> 1 </button>
                    <button onclick="setvalue('2')"> 2 </button>
                    <button onclick="setvalue('3')"> 3</button>

                </div>
                <div class="calc-row">
                    <button id="zerobutton" onclick="setvalue('0')"> 0 </button>
                    <button id="dotbutton" onclick="dotfun()"> .</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calc-col2">
                <button onclick="dividefun()"> /</button>
                <button onclick="multiplyfun()"> * </button>
                <button onclick="minusfun()"> - </button>
                <button onclick="plusfun()"> + </button>
                <button id="equalbtn" onclick="equalfun()"> = </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

CSS -

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "sourcesans";
}

.calculator {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

#textbox {
    flex: 4;
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#textbox > #tagone {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#buttondivision {
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* break-inside: avoid; */
}

.calc-col1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex:2;
    width:100%;
}

.calc-col2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex:1;
    height:100%;
}
/* .calc-col2:last-child {
    flex:2;
} */

.calc-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width:100%;
    /* flex:1; */
}

.calc-row > button {
    flex:1;
}

.calc-col2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    flex:1;
}

#clearbutton, #zerobutton, #equalbtn {
    flex: 2;
}

button {
    background-color: rgb(199, 255, 192);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 0px solid black;
    border-top:none;
    border-left:none;
    font-size:2em;
    margin: 1px;
}

.calc-row > button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(199, 255, 141);
}

.calc-row2 > button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(199, 255, 141);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set height for `#buttondivision`. This will allow flexbox to calculate relative height for buttons inside `.calc-col1`

E.g. something like here - https://codepen.io/AlphaOmegaBetaGamma/pen/abYaKLo